# Удаление элемента li jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Предупреждаю сразу в JavaScript не шарю... По возможности максимально для чайника объясните... Вот с горем пополам написал:

```
function addnew(nameid) {
    $('#' + nameid + ' ul li:last').cloneWithEvents().removeClass(nameid + ($('#' + nameid + ' ul li').size())).addClass(nameid + ($('#' + nameid + ' ul li').size() + 1)).appendTo('#' + nameid + ' ul');
}

function dellast(nameid) {
    $('#' + nameid + ' ul li:last').remove();
}
```

и

```
<div class="paplus" id="myform">
  <ul id="myList" class="paplusul">
    <li><input name="message[]" type="text" value="" size="10" /><input name="persent[]" type="text" value="" size="50" /></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="pm"><img src="/images/plus.png" onclick="addnew('myform')"><img src="images/minus.png" onclick="dellast('myform')"></div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том что при удалении - удаляются все элементы поочередно вплоть до первого... и потом добавить нельзя потому как нечего клонировать... Как дописать проверку в код удаления?

И как добавить эффект плавного появления нового поля и плавного удаления старого поля...

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul id="wrap">
<li id="add">+</li>
<li id="dellete">-</li>
<li class="wrapLi">
    <input/>
</li>
</ul>
```

и

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addInput='<input/>';
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#wrapLi').append(addInput);
    });
    $('#dellete').click(function(){
        var l=$('#wrapLi input').length;
        $('#wrapLi input').eq(l-1).remove();
    });
</script>
```

Добавляет, удаляет инпуты в li с id wrapLi. (По клику на +/-) УДАЛЯЕТ всегда один последний!

Comment: ну понятно что форм будет... не в этом дело... Да и обращаюсь я не к элементу input... а к li... с чего вы вообще взяли что мне надо обращатся к input... яж написал что мне надо чтоб удалялись все поочередно li кроме первого....

Comment: Извиняюсь! Тогда так `$('#myList li').slice(1).remove()` удалятся все li начиная со второго и до конца выборк ...

Comment: Такой код удаляет не по одному элементу li, а сразу все кроме первого... Да и если судить из логики то удалять если начнут со 2-го то будет некрасиво...  например будет внутри написано поочереди "1 2 3 4 5 6" и если начнет удалять со 2-го то при удалении 2-х полей результат будет не "1 2 3 4", а " 1 4 5 6"... Есть ещё идеи какие-то???

Comment: Ну так удаляйте всегда последние два или 10 или сколько нужно! Если же нужно удалять поочередно (хотя они и так поочередно удаляются - иначе никак), то циклом each(function(){ Здесь выполниться код для каждого элемента выборки}) либо while(){} или другими доступными циклами в javascript. А вообще будет проще если вы опишите контекст применения ... В моей голове нет ваших мыслей ...

Comment: Существует 1 блок LI в нем находятся 2 поля INPUT при нажатии на ПЛЮС срабатывает функция addnew(nameid) и блок LI дублируется снизу... И так постоянно пока нажимаешь ПЛЮС... Когда нажимается МИНУС срабатывает функция dellast('myform') и удаляет последний элемент.

Вот весь принцип данного кода... и описание что оно делает... Проблема в том что при удалении оно удаляет поочередно но так-же удаляет и первый элемент LI. как ограничить чтоб первый элемент не удаляло.... Если можете пожалуйста код примера киньте... а то яж написал я крайне не силен в JS.